# Actors or Future for methods with mathematical operations in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, future

I have a block of code (as shown below) and I want to make it work concurrently in Scala.

```
    for(i <- 0 until ca1.length){
      for(j <- 0 until ca2.length){
        val afpchain = algorithm.align(ca1(i), ca2(j))
        afpchain.setName1(label1(i))
        afpchain.setName2(label2(j))
        println(label1(i) + " " + label2(j) + afpchain.getChainRmsd + " " + afpchain.getCalculationTime )
        results.write(label1(i) + " " + label2(j) + " " + afpchain.getChainRmsd + "\n")
        val num1 = new Number(j+1,i+1,afpchain.getChainRmsd(),Format)
        sheet.addCell(num1)
      }
    }
```

First of all I would like to know if it is possible. So far only concurrent programming examples I have seen are about chat rooms, messages and rather simpler stuff but this block covers bunch of methods that do numerical operations (i.e. `align`, `getChainRmsd` and also `ca1` and `ca2` are `ArrayBuffer`s of `Double` coordinate values). What would you advise me and how should I write the code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Running this block concurrently with other code needs just a `Future` wrapped around it. However I think you rather want to parallelize it. Could you please clarify?

Comment: This loop takes a lot of time so I basically want to divide it into two and make it work in a parallel manner. For example, I tried to use `Actors` by dividing the length to two (one block for `i = 0` to `ca1.length/2` and another for `ca1.length/2` to `ca1.length`) but I got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.... lets say you have an actor that, for each message, spawns a worker actor and calculates the Number for you (and whatever else you need that is parallelizable), which you can query with something like:

```
val theNum = ask(myActor, new MyMessage(i, j))
```

MyMessage is just a case class you define in the companion object to MyActor:

```
case class MyMessage(i: Int, j: Int)
```

ok, that's nice, now we can do (off the top of my head, may have bugs):

```
val myNums = 
  for(i <- 0 until ca1.length) yield {
    for(j <- 0 until ca2.length) yield {
      theNum <- ask(myActor, new MyMessage(i, j)).mapTo[Number]       
    }
  }
```

So your results can be grabbed thusly: (using Await for simplicity, not because I like it):

```
val result = Await.result(myNums, 10 seconds).flatten.asInstanceOf[Seq[Number]]
```

Now you'll want to foreach over the result, do your printing/logging and adding of numbers to your "sheet" (whatever that is) -- assuming you didn't take care of that in the actor (depends on what your sheet is and what you need, I suppose).

Note: you could also make myActor a router by doing something like:

```
val myActor = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withRouter( RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 10))
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand it completely but do I have to wait to get results? It takes roughly around 0.3 seconds to calculate one element of this loop, what I am trying to do is to make it run faster. Is it going to help me for that? Would it be easier if I just used `Runnable` of Java?

Comment: See edits -- to distribute your workload amongst several actors you can either 1.) Have your actor spawn a worker actor for each request... or 2.) Declare "myActor" as a router with a set number of child actors.  The individual calculations will be done concurrently.  The Await statement waits for all of them to be done.  This should be faster than doing them serially.

Comment: Also note that Awaits *are* blocking.  Generally, they should be avoided if possible (I use them in my unit tests because they're simple).  A fully realized implementation and an accompanying explanation of Actor Systems would be... rather long for a stackoverflow answer.